# Yeoman/Grunt usemin subfolders

Tags: path, gruntjs, yeoman, subdirectory, grunt-usemin

I'm having a horrible time using yeoman/grunt and usemin - trying to get output files to work at the same time as writing the correct path inside the html, when I have subfolders.

My basic set up is that there are top level pages (eg. index.html) and also language specific pages in sub folders (en, de, fr etc.) - each of those will have common js files (like jquery) but also language specific js files (same for css, but keeping it simple...)

```
– Gruntfile.js
– app
    |– index.html
    |– js
        jquery.js
            |– en
                english.js
            |– de
                german.js
    |– css
    |– en
        |– index.html
    |– de
        |– index.html
– dist
```

So basically - there is the top level index.html which has jquery etc. - So the script tag in there might look like

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

or with rev

```
<script src="js/123.jquery.js"></script>
```

But in en/index.html the script tag should look like
(for common - like jquery)

```
<script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
```

or with rev.

```
<script src="../js/123.jquery.js"></script>
```

It's the ../ that is the trouble.

I can get the js file built but not rev'd, or rev'd but empty, or build and rev'd but in the wrong location (most often outside/above both the app and dist folders!)

In the en/index.html - I just can't work out what the build:js should look like
eg.

```
<!-- build:js js/jquery.js -->
<script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:js js/en/english/jquery.js -->
<script src="../js/en/english.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

I've tried every combinition I can think of - it seems to boil down to if I write a ../ in the build:js path, then the actual file is place 1 level up from the app folder, but writes the path in the html correctly. If I leave the ../ out, it puts the file in the right place, but the html doesn't have the ../ in either (which it clearly needs) - so how do I say that I want the output file to reference one level up (out of en/ folder) but have grunt *not* put it one level up (outside dist folder!)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a very similar problem. I was hosting my grunt-generated site on S3 using their static website option. Locally, the usemin generated content was working perfectly (with absolute paths), but since I had the site in a bucket on S3, it need the full absolute path (with domain) to the asset files to actually work.

Enter [grunt-replace](https://github.com/outaTiME/grunt-replace). Using a search/replace pattern was the only way I found to actually get this accomplished. For me, I just needed to replace "/assets/" with "http://s3domain.com/bucket/site-name/assets/". Here's my grunt task definition:

```
replace: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      patterns: [
        {
          match: /\/assets\//,
          replacement: 'http://s3domain.com/bucket/site-name/assets/'
        }
      ]
    },
    files: [
      {
        expand: true,
        src: ['dist/**/*.html']
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I've added that to my `deploy` task so that it only runs right before I'm about to push to S3.

For your cases, you could probably let `usemin` do its thing, then only replace files in subdirectories (like `en` or `es`) and change the asset paths to have `../` before them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it actually helped me to get around the similar issue I had, see question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20290757/dynamic-path-in-yeoman-build-comment-tag