# Dynamic path in Yeoman build comment tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-applications, gruntjs, yeoman

Is there a way to get dynamic path into the **Yeoman** build tag, e.g. for

`<!-- build:js scripts/modernizr.js -->`

The use-case would be to push in a different path in the layout for differently nested pages, either `/` to webroot or `../../` to an upper level, e.g. something like

`<!-- build:js <%= config.path.script %>/modernizr.js -->`

Related topic has already been discussed in a question of [Yeoman/Grunt usemin subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346022/yeoman-grunt-usemin-subfolders), but what about a more graceful/flexible solution? Ideas?

Comment: If you need more complex control, it is my opinion you should do this inside your application/template system logic. Yeoman usemin is a simple tool for simple need. Anything more complex is application business logic IMO.

Answer (score 0):

If you compile to static HTML, you can have a look at my [grunt-magic-paths](https://github.com/ben-eb/grunt-magic-paths) task. It can take a user defined needle (default is `path:`) and automatically resolve the path to a file based on its name alone. So you could do this:

```
<script src="path:modernizr.js"></script>
```

And based on the output directory it will resolve the path names automatically. The one caveat is that a linked path must be a unique one; i.e. you can't link two different copies (versions) of Modernizr with the same filename.

You may find though that for larger applications having a build step like this is brittle, especially as your application grows and the number of paths increase. I'd **strongly** recommend the use of absolute paths for anything larger than a personal portfolio; you can then keep the domain path in a config file (in JS, something like this):

```
module.exports = 'http://mydomain.com';
```

Then for use in production:

```
var domain = require('config.js');
console.log(domain);
// => http://mydomain.com
```

Change the `config.js` file depending on your environment; you may want to `.gitignore` it, and provide a sample config with dummy data instead. Because Grunt runs on top of Node you then have this config in your build step as well as your application (again I'm assuming you're writing a Node application, for other projects you may prefer JSON or PHP config files).